# Run program in background after the click of a button

Tags: java, background-process

I want to make my program run in the background after you click a button.
I'm creating a rickroll (in 2015 yeh) and when you click a button I want to play the song never gonna give you up from rick astley and get the frame closed and run in a process, so the song still continues. I already got the part of clicking the button and starting the song, but how can I make it continue in a process?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that "continue in a process" is what you want.

Just close your frame, allow your main message loop to end, and before returning from your `main()` function block waiting for the sound to end.  Or, if you don't know how to block waiting for the sound to end, then calculate how many milliseconds long your sound is, and just `Thread.sleep()` for that many milliseconds.

Comment: Okay, and if I want to make the song loop, so he can only stop it from the process manager?

Comment: Well then, keep playing the song in a loop, after your frame has been closed, and before exiting the app.  Naughty-naughty you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I did: after clicking the button I made the visibility of the frame false.